# PyCharm couldn't find a pre-installed module os but can still use it

Tags: python, pycharm

I've using Pycharm for a while now. And recently I noticed that the `import os` line is highlighted in red with an error message of `No module named os`. (Using Python 3.8.4)

[image: OS module not found]

But when launching the script(Via PyCharm) it's importing it without any errors.
The exact same thing is also happening with a module named `webbrowser`.

Why does it say this? And how do I fix this?

Comment: i often find right clicking on a file and clicking "run" runs the last file I ran again, not the file I've clicked on. are you _sure_ it's running this file?

Comment: @joel It's very annoying that PyCharm can run a Python script that is not the one you're selecting right now. But Nah, I was running the right now.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Python from the Microsoft Store. And changing the Interpreter from `...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe` to `...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe` fixed it.

(The first directory gave me an invalid SDK error)

Or maybe just the fact that I remove and added back the Interpreter was the thing that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using python 3.8.5 on a mac, and found the trick to be to quit pycharm, delete the .idea file in the project directory and restart pycharm.